# Android Firestore view changes between snapshots from document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We can view changes between snapshots from collection as [google official document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) example:

```
db.collection("cities")
        .whereEqualTo("state", "CA")
        .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
                    return;
                }

                for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    switch (dc.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:
                            Log.d(TAG, "New city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                            break;
                        case MODIFIED:
                            Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                            break;
                        case REMOVED:
                            Log.d(TAG, "Removed city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

But if the query is on a document, how can we get the `DocumentChange` informations: ADDED/MODIFIED/REMOVED?

```
db.collection("cities")
        .document("SF") //Query on document "SF"
        .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            ....
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

CollectionReference's [addSnapshotListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E)) method:

> Starts listening to this query.

Which means that it adds a listener on that particular collection reference for every document change. With other words, the listeners fires every time a document is added, modified or removed on that particular reference on which was added.

While DocumentReference's [addSnapshotListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot%3E)) method:

> Starts listening to the document referenced by this DocumentReference.

Which means that it adds a listener on a single document reference to listen for changes. In this case the listener fires for every property that is added, modified or removed within the document. If you think that you'll be notified with the particular property that was changes, please note that it's not possible. There are no field-level permissions or access to a document. It's the entire document, or nothing. Cloud Firestore listeners fire on the document level. There is no way to get triggered with just particular fields in a document.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is query that specific document from collection:
Change line:

```
.whereEqualTo("state", "CA")
```

to line:

```
.whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), "CA")
```

Full example:

```
    rootRefs.collection("cities")
            .whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), "CA") //change this line
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        switch (dc.getType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                Log.d(TAG, "New city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                            case MODIFIED:
                                Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                            case REMOVED:
                                Log.d(TAG, "Removed city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```